# Setting the height of the UITableView when the height of the cells is dynamic

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I am working on an app for iOS in swift 3, in which there is a view controller having other views (`UIImageView`, `UICollectionView`) and the content is scrollable by `UIScrollView`.
I want to add a `UITableView` somewhere in middle. The `UITableView` will have cells of dynamic height. Everything is working except I am unable to set the height of the `UITableView` to wrap its content so that all the cells of `UITableView` are visible without scrolling through table. I want to turn off the scrolling of the `UITableView` and the table view to set its height to make all the cells visible without scrolling.

I simply can't multiply the height of a cell to the number of rows as the height of each cell is also dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
// add observer to your tableView to get its proper height when its 
//data is loaded. you can do this in view did load
 self.YourTableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize",options: .new, context: nil)

// override this metod to observe for tableView height change
 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?){
if(keyPath == "contentSize"){

    if let newvalue = change?[.newKey]
    {
        let newsize  = newvalue as! CGSize
        // make height constraint for your table view and set to new size.
        // and here you can check if newSize.height is more than required tha you can set it to default
        if(newsize.height < defaultHeight)
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = newsize.height

    }else{
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = defaultHeight

    }
}
}
```

Let me know if you face any trouble

And remember to remove observer otherwise app will crash

```
deinit {
 self.YourTableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Vikky. You saved my life. :) Working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You need not calculate height manually just use `tableView.contentSize.height`.

Comment: tableView.contentSize.height always don't provide correct height.So for the working solution see my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you controller have many nest scrollViews, *tableView.contentSize.height* could not provide actual contentHeight. So if you want to get the contentHeight (to set the tableview`s height), there has two ways:

1. do a delay action:

   > DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:DispatchTime.now() + 0.1) {
   >                  // get contentHeight and set tableView`s frame
   >              }
2. get correct height in scrollView delegate:

   > func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   >              let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
   >         }